# How to zip 2 list columns on Python Polars?

Tags: python-polars

I have a dataframe with columns A, B and C where B and C are list columns.
I need to combine then like follows:

```
Original:
┌─────┬─────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ A   ┆ B               ┆ C            │
│ --- ┆ ---             ┆ ---          │
│ i64 ┆ list[str]       ┆ list[i64]    │
╞═════╪═════════════════╪══════════════╡
│ t   ┆ ["a", "v", "x"] ┆ [11, 12, 14] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ u   ┆ ["f", "g", "h"] ┆ [41, 42, 43] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ v   ┆ ["p", "o", "i"] ┆ [66, 77, 88] │
└─────┴─────────────────┴──────────────┘

Final: 
┌─────┬─────────────────────────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ zip(B,C)                            │
│ --- ┆ ---                                 │
│ i64 ┆ object(?)                           │
╞═════╪═════════════════════════════════════╡
│ t   ┆ [('a', 11), ('v', 12), ('x', 14) ]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ u   ┆ [('f', 41), ('g', 42), ('h', 43) ]  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ v   ┆ [('p', 66), ('o', 77), ('i', 88) ]  │
└─────┴─────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Using just Python I would do a `zip()`, but this approach does not scale.
I thought about using `explode()` on the lists, casting then as string and join the results using a separator, but that does not feels right, and I would have problems to keep the data on column `A` correctly related to the exploded result.

Is there another way to achieve this result?

Comment: Can you add the snippet that creates you input data? That we we don't have to copy manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Polars, you can use a struct for this.

```py
(
    df.explode(["B", "C"])
    .select(["A", pl.struct(["B", "C"]).alias("struct")])
    .groupby("A")
    .agg(pl.col("struct"))
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬────────────────────────────────┐
│ A   ┆ struct                         │
│ --- ┆ ---                            │
│ str ┆ list[struct[2]]                │
╞═════╪════════════════════════════════╡
│ u   ┆ [{"f",41}, {"g",42}, {"h",43}] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ v   ┆ [{"p",66}, {"o",77}, {"i",88}] │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ t   ┆ [{"a",11}, {"v",12}, {"x",14}] │
└─────┴────────────────────────────────┘
```

The result is a list of struct.